# onAdFailedtoLoad: 3 error only on Android version of Flutter app for AdMob

Tags: android, flutter, admob, ads

I am trying to load banner, interstitial and rewarded video ads in my app. I have tested my code thoroughly and all my code works with test IDs. I replaced the test ID's with my actual Admob ID's and it works on the iOS version of my app, however when I tested the same on the APK release version of my app on my device it didn't load, I have integrated Facebook mediation as well selected 'contains ads' in the Developer Play Console. Recently, I had unpublished my app to make a few changes. I uploaded the app with my AdMob ID's and I'm still facing this problem. What can I do about it? My Admob account is on good terms with the AdMob policies.

```
W/flutter onAdFailedToLoad: 3
```

Comment: As i remember error code 3 mean everything is okay from your side, but your AdMob id not have any ad assigned to it yet, it can take time, if everything working on develop , then it's not your fault, just wait

Comment: The ads are loading on the iOS version but not on the Android version specifically? Should I just wait or is it because my app was unpublished for a few days? I have read the answers to this question stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3 although I'm not sure what is wrong

Comment: Nothing is wrong from your side,  i faced the same problem and even everyone face this when they implement,, but yes there can be other reasons too, like your admob id is blocked due to extensive click on ad form same device, but i don't think it's your case

Comment: if you are not sure then just make a new ad id and then wait. if it's working with test id then it's not your fault, there is no solution other then wait

Comment: On my side, Test ad loaded when I changed SmartBanner to Banner  and set a test devideId.

Answer (score 1):

> W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3

As per the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL) you are getting the following error code:

> **public static final int ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL**
>
> The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of
> ad inventory.
>
> Constant Value: 3

So, everything is okay from your side, and Admob didn't have an right ad for your placement.

Comment: And what is supposed to happen now? Should we just wait?